# Iframe escondendo conteúdo

Tags: html, css, iframe

Tenho um `iframe` que recebe "interacoes.php" que é um select.
Mas o `iframe` esconde os conteúdos por conta do `height="100%"`. Se eu coloco `height=20000px;` ele mostra tudo.

Como posso fazer pra aparecer tudo automaticamente?

Não quero colocar um height fixo, por que tanto faz o conteúdo ser pequeno ou grande, vai de acordo com oque tem no select.

*HTML:*

```
 <iframe src="interacao.php" width="100%" style="height:100%; min-height:900px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: Você poderia habilitar o scrolling?

Comment: Obrigado por responder gabriel. Não seria ideal habilitar o scroll. O interessante é o height automatico :/

Answer (score 1):

Se você deseja que o conteúdo dentro do iframe seja exibido automaticamente, sem que seja necessário definir manualmente uma altura específica, você pode adicionar o seguinte JavaScript ao seu arquivo HTML:

php

function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
      newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
      newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
  }

E então adicione o atributo "id" ao seu iframe, para que o JavaScript possa identificá-lo:

bash

Isso fará com que a altura e a largura do iframe sejam ajustadas automaticamente de acordo com o conteúdo que ele está carregando.